Hebrew text wrapping unexpectedly with RaggedLeft in tblr
I'm facing an issue where Hebrew text is wrapping onto a new line inside a tblr environment, even though there seems to be enough space to fit the remaining text on the current line. I'm using the ragged2e package to apply \RaggedLeft for the second row of my table, but the Hebrew text still breaks unexpectedly.

MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = { r X[l] },
  row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
  row{2} = {font=\RaggedLeft\large}, %<= I must do somethig wrong here...
  width=\linewidth,
  hlines,
  vlines
}
Substitution  & Figs or grapes \\ 
 & \RL{\texthebrew{יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ, יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ, שֶׁיִּתַּמּוּ אוֹיְבֵינוּ וְשׂוֹנְאֵינוּ וְכָל מְבַקְּשֵׁי רָעָתֵנוּ.}} \\ 
Phonetic    & Yehi ratzon milfanekha, Adonai Eloheinu veElohei avoteinu, sheyitamu oyeveinu vesoneinu vekhol mevakshei ra'atenu \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


It is indeed tough to reconcile RTL text, with tabular environments and especially with changes to alignment. The issues here are more complex than just your use of ragged2e, though I admittedly haven't time to completely debug and explain them.
Notwithstanding, I do have a solution for you, which I provide below. I've also taken some liberties to implement my own suggestions, beyond those you requested (including removal of vertical lines in the table, which I also do not advise). You should be able to easily revert such modifications, should you not also prefer them.
Please note that you will now need to compile via XeLaTeX, if you were not already doing so.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{bidi} % for proper RTL support

\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL} % use a proper Hebrew font

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec = {r X[l]},
      row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
      row{2} = {font=\RaggedLeft\large},
      width=\linewidth,
      rowsep=2pt,
      stretch=0,
      hlines = {1pt}
    }
    %
    \toprule
    Substitution  & Figs or grapes \\ 
    \midrule
     & \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\begin{RTL}
        \texthebrew{יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ, יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ,}\\ %<- remove, to fill row with one extra word!
        \texthebrew{שֶׁיִּתַּמּוּ אוֹיְבֵינוּ וְשׂוֹנְאֵינוּ וְכָל מְבַקְּשֵׁי רָעָתֵנוּ.}
        \end{RTL}} \\ 
    Phonetic    & Yehi ratzon milfanekha, Adonai Eloheinu veElohei avoteinu, sheyitamu oyeveinu vesoneinu vekhol mevakshei ra'atenu \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}

which produces the the below output:

You may also view this in Overleaf.

Best wishes for your Musaf service and wishing you a Shanah Tova!
